# How to do multiple treatment meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis

I would like to compare 3 different treatments (no one treatment is considered the placebo, and these are not randomized control trials) from multiple studies in a meta-analysis. I am using the software called "Review Manager" from the Cochrane society, and I am wondering if what I am doing is correct or not:

Say A, B, and C are the different treatments. I make the direct comparisons A vs. B, A vs. C, and B and C to obtain the odds ratios, confidence intervals, Z scores, p values, etc. Then I use the results from A vs. B and A vs. C to calculate the indirect comparison for B vs. C, obtaining the odds ratio and SE.

**A vs. B**[image: A vs. B]
Ignore where it says risk ratio, the studies that I will be looking at are all retrospective.

**A vs. C**[image: A vs. B] Ignore where it says risk ratio, the studies that I will be looking at are all retrospective.

I make another analysis with both direct and indirect B vs. C on Review Manager to obtain the odds ratio and statistics for this.

**Direct and Indirect B vs. C**
[image: Results of the analysis] Ignore where it says risk ratio, the studies that I will be looking at are all retrospective.

Indirect B vs. C was determined using:
[image: Indirect calculations]

L or l = log

Please tell me if I am doing this correctly, and whether if this is valid.

If so, how would I report the results from the analysis between the direct and indirect B vs. C? This would be telling me whether if the difference between B and C is significant?

How would I report the overall findings comparing the 3 different treatments?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: are you trying to perform a network meta-analysis? http://www.bmj.com/content/346/bmj.f2914

Comment: In your third figure, how did you come up with RR=0.42 for the indirect comparison of B vs C?

Comment: @charles Yes, I am trying to perform a network meta-analysis.

Comment: @Wolfgang I've added the calculations above for indirect B vs C

Comment: What you are doing is correct but I haven't recalculated them to check your math. This is called the 'Bucher Method' or 'adjusted indirect comparison'. It can be done in a network meta-analysis (or multiple treatment comparison), but also as you have done using GIV to pool the direct and indirect estimates.

Comment: Would I need to limit the threshold for my p value, since I am essentially doing 3 comparisons? @abousetta The numbers in the example are not important, I just wanted to know if the method is valid pertaining to my question...Thanks

Comment: I still cannot figure out your computations. If $RR = .39$ for A vs B, then $RR = 1/.39 = 2.56$ for B vs A. And if $RR = .77$ for A vs C, then $RR = 2.56 \times .77 = 1.97$ for indirect B vs C. And even if you meant C vs B, it would be $1/1.97 = .51$, which also isn't $.42$.

Comment: @Wolfgang you have to use log of RR to do the calculations.

Comment: Actually you don't. You can do the calculations on the RR scale and work with multiplication/division to get the answer. RR for B vs A is $RR_1 = risk_B / risk_A$. And RR for A vs C is $RR_2 = risk_A / risk_C$. And then $RR_1 \times RR_2 = (risk_B / risk_A) \times (risk_A / risk_C) = risk_B / risk_C$ which is the RR for indirect B vs C. Instead, one can work on the log scale and then do the computations with addition/subtraction. The answer will be the same. Aside from that, you used $-0.06$ and $-0.93$ as the log values. I can't figure out how you got those values.

Comment: @Wolfgang Thanks. I got the example from elsewhere, so disregard the specific numbers. I would just like to find out if this is the right method for addressing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since this one was effectively answered in the comments this answer just brings it together for the benefit of future readers. Any intellectual credit goes to @abousetta and @wolfgang not to me.

The method outlined is known as Bucher's method after the first author of [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0895435697000498) in J Clin Epid entitled "The results of direct and indirect comparisons in meta--analysis of randomized controlled trials". It is also discussed in the Cochrane handbook. The indirect effect is obtained by subtraction of the log risks for the comparison of the two conditions with a common comparator. The method of network meta-analysis would be appropriate and might have advantages since techniques exist for exploring inconsistency and software for network meta-analysis usually provides interesting graphical display options.